# How to use jQuery on Django Media Form

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

i'm trying to inject extra javascript and jQuery on Django form through Media meta class.

I return a form to the create.html template and rendered ok with js functions was executed but not jQuery functions.

base.html for templates:

```
...
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
...
{% block javascript %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('base.html js');
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

create.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('create.html js');
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
{% block content %}
  {% if form %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {% include 'form.html' %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

form.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('create.html js');
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
...
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field|add_class:"form-control" }}
{% endfor %}
```

forms.py:

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Media:
    js = (
        'js/custom_tag_widget.js',
    )
```

custom_tag_widget.js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  console.log('form media js');
});
```

I have this console output and appear an error:

```
form.html js
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
base.html js
create.html js
```

Anybody could help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like jquery is not loaded correctly.

I guess it's because your custom js `custom_tag_widget.js` loaded before `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`.

Check ordering of you files in Network.

If jquery is loaded after your custom js you can move your block `content` after block `javascript` in your HTML files

Answer (score 0):

Please check `Network` tab in Dev Tools, to check if your js file does not return 404, and the path to `custom_tag_widget.js` is correct.

Also, it's possible that static in your project is not configured correctly.

Please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Is jquery also loaded successfully?

Comment: you can try to use pure js function instead of jquery, like

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     // your code       
 });

instead of $(document).ready

Comment: Ok, it is an option, but I would like to learn how to use jQuery in Django Media Form